# What are "relaxation constants" in ode systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In my reading, I came across the following ODE system:

$$\lambda_1 \dot x = f(x,y)$$
$$\lambda_2 \dot y = g(x,y)$$, where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are positive constants.

Then, I saw that the authors call $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ "relaxation constants". But, what does that mean? I mean, what does these constants do and what do they "relax"?

Comment: Could you quote an excerpt of article where you've found this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relaxation is an adjustment of the speed of an iterative process that makes the updates more gentle (under-relaxation) or more aggressive (over-relaxation). A prototypical example of over-relaxation is described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation). An example of under-relaxation is in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/935159/).

In your context, it's only the ratio of constants $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$ that really matters, since multiplying them both by the same factor does nothing but change the time scale. One could just as well use only $\lambda_2$ (this is what is done in the [gentlest ascent](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1991) article).

Making $\lambda_2$ large compared to $\lambda_1$ will make $y$ change its value more slowly compared to $x$, and vice versa. The effect on the speed and stability of convergence depends on what $f$ and $g$ are.  Typically one carries out the analysis  for general $\lambda_{1,2}$ and then picks the values that help achieve desired estimates at the end.

As an illustration, one can think of *mass* in Newtonian dynamics as a relaxation coefficient: 
$$
\begin{split}\dot x &= v  \\
m\dot v &= F(x)
\end{split}
$$
Here $x$ and $v$ are the position and velocity of a particle of mass $m$. The coefficient $m$ determines how quickly the particle will change its velocity under the action of the force. Depending on the geometry of the force field, this can have a complex effect on dynamics.

Edgar Allan Poe described something of the sort in his story [A Descent into the Maelström](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Descent_into_the_Maelstr%C3%B6m).

Comment: I now understand that the relaxation constants basically fine-tunes the rate of changes. However, wouldn't attaching extra relaxation constants like $\lambda 1, \lambda 2$ amount to changing the underlying phyiscs/nature of the problem?

Comment: It would. But if the goal is to find an extremum or a saddle point, what matters most is the destination. One can take various paths toward that destination.